# Finding members of the list that share a common element

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have a list:

`{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}`

and I want to find all the members of that list that share a common element. So, for instance, if I say that this element is 1, I would get a list `{{1},{1,2},{1,2,3},{1,2,3,4}}`. I played around with `Cases` and `Intersection` but couldn't figure it out. I'd appreciate some hints. Thanks.

Comment: Use `MemberQ` to check if a element is part of a list. Combine this with `Select`, `Cases` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
sel[list_, element_] := Select[list, MemberQ[#, element] &];
sel[l, 1]
```

produces the output

{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 3):

Let's assemble a `SparseArray` whose entry `A[[i,j]]` is `1` precisely if `i` is a member of the `j`th sublist (and `0` otherwise).

```
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
A = SparseArray[
   Join @@ MapIndexed[{y, x} \[Function] Thread[{y[[1]], x}], a] -> 1,
   {Max[a], Length[a]}
   ];
```

Then you obtain the indices of the sublists that contain the entry `i` by `A[[i]]["AdjacencyLists"]`, e.g.

```
i = 1;
idx = A[[i]]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> {1, 5, 8, 10}

The actual sublist have to be look up from the original list of lists:

```
a[[idx]]
```

> {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

The nice thing about the `SparseArray` `A` is that it can be reused for multiple lookups. Actually,

> A["AdjacencyLists"]

returns already the sublist indices for all entries. Moreover, the `SparseArray` data structure is highly optimized for such lookups. You will hardly be able to make it faster in *Mathematica*

The drawback is that you are limited to positive integer labels. But that is easily compensated if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote helpful answers; this is what drives to community.